# Moxy conditional element output

Tags: java, jax-rs, moxy

Is it possible to only output an element (as XML or JSON) conditionally based on some runtime information?

I worked out the answer myself and thought I'd share it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
return null
```

**Example**

I have a list 'alertStems' and a boolean joinConditionIsOr but only want to output a joinCondition when the list is > 1.

```
private List<String> alertStems;
private Boolean joinConditionOR;
...
@XmlElement(name="joinCondition")
public Boolean isJoinConditionOR() {
    if (alertStems.getList().size() > 1) {
        return joinConditionOR;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```